# Mysql группировка с MIN()

Tags: mysql, сортировка, min

пишу MYSQL запрос который должен выводить самые дешевые товары, сгруппированные по полю `name` и у которых `count` > 0

Вот сам запрос:

```
SELECT `s1`.*
    FROM `products` AS `s1`
    JOIN (
      SELECT `name`, MIN(`price`) AS `price`             
      FROM `products` 
      WHERE `category`=1  
      GROUP BY `name`) AS `s2`
      ON `s1`.`name` = `s2`.`name` AND `s1`.`price` = `s2`.`price` 
    WHERE `category`=1 LIMIT 0, 25
```

Не пойму куда вставить `count`>0, чтобы выводился сгруппированный товар с наименьшей ценой у которого количество (поле `count`) больше 0 (если такой имеется), если такого нет, то просто с наименьшей ценой

---

### [перемещено из комментария]

> Версия сервера: 5.5.64-MariaDB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products ( 
    id int(20) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    category varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
    name varchar(128) NOT NULL, 
    price decimal(10,2) NOT NULL, 
    count int(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: `count` поле в базе с количеством товара.  необходимо сгруппировать товары по имени и вывести с товар с минимальной ценой который в наличии.
-- Структура таблицы `products`
-- Версия сервера: 5.5.64-MariaDB
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(4) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Неясно. Выложите пример данных (в форме INSERT INTO) и нужный результат для именно этих данных (без LIMIT). И не в комментарии, а в тексте вопроса.

Comment: *Не пойму куда вставить count>0* Чисто по смыслу - и в подзапрос, и в основной запрос (т.е. в дополнение к `category=1`).